# Jquery animate shifting text

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

When using animate to change some  in html, jquery animate 'moves'/shifts the text around instead of just replacing the text.

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2VYn/

```
    function cycleIntro() {
        var whoArr = ["colleagues", "girlfriend", "homies", "nemesis", "lover", "dad", "mom", "brother", "sister", "enemies", "friends", "classmates", "best&nbsp;friend", "imaginary&nbsp;friend", "grandma'"];
        var whatArr = ["pool", "backgammon", "dart", "chess", "ping&nbsp;pong", "bob", "headsup&nbsp;poker", "ludo", "yatzy", "foosball", "tennis", "street&nbsp;basket", "golf", "water&nbsp;polo"];

        var whotxt = whoArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * whoArr.length)];
        while ($("#intro #who").html() == whotxt) {
            whotxt = whoArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * whoArr.length)];
        }
        var whattxt = whatArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * whatArr.length)];
        while ($("#intro #what").html() == whattxt) {
            whattxt = whatArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * whatArr.length)];
        }
        $("#intro #who").animate({ width: "toggle" }, 200, function () {
            $("#intro #who").html(whotxt).animate({ width: "toggle" }, 300, function () {
                $("#intro #what").delay(50).animate({ width: "toggle" }, 200, function () {
                    $("#intro #what").html(whattxt).animate({ width: "toggle" }, 300, function () {
                        setTimeout(cycleIntro, 1500);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    setTimeout(cycleIntro, 1500);
```

Does anyone know how to adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings the `vertical-align` property of the spans you're manipulating to `bottom` fixes the issue. I've updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x2VYn/3/).

Comment: Using height doesn't solve the problem. the 'width' is the way i want it to look. However, the error occurs whenever it toggles the words - it seems like it inserts some kind of padding/margin, which moves/shifts the text around.

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood the question. Please see my updated answer.